# Xcode keep replacing my existing bundle id with dash

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I already have existing app which its bundle identifier start with digit.
The app is transferred from third party to our account.
[Here is the bundle id SS from itunesconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvzBR.jpg)

Xcode however, always replacing first digit of my bundle id with dash
4UDBLABLA.com.company.appname => -UDBLABLA.com.company.appname

I've try some workaround to keep my original bundle id, but also get replaced with dash when uploading to app store

How can i upload my app with these bundle id?

- Xcode version: 8.2.1 (8C1002)
- System Information:
  OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: First part is team ID, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are not a lot of details here. But I was there yesterday, and I know how hard it can be to describe. You type the bundle ID in correctly, and it keeps putting back the same mistake. I had the same problem - the first character (a number) was automatically replaced by a '-'.

In Xcode, search through the project for the good part of the address. In your example, search for 'UDBLABLA.com.company.appname'.  I found the entry that kept going wrong, and a more obscure second copy that it had presumably created for itself somewhere deep in the settings. When I fixed that second copy (there were several entries for different sorts of build, but they were all in the same place), all was well. Until the next thing.